# EF Code First DB gets dropped if used in different projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an application which uses Entity Framework Code First models.

The structure of the project looks like this

- **Application.Models** *POCO objects*
- **Application.EF** *EF Data Context and repositories*
- **Application.Web.MVC** *The web application (the designer)*

The context initializer looks like this:

```
public class DBContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DBContext>
{
     protected override void Seed(DBContext context)
     {

     }
 }
```

Now, i have another API Application which gets the data from database as API calls. The project looks like this:

- **Application.Api.MVC** *The MVC4 API Project, containing DTO objects*
- **Application.Models** *Same project*
- **Application.EF** *Same project*

Even if i don't change the POCO classes (inside `Application.Models` project), Entity Framework detects that the Metadata has changed, and tries to drop and re-create the database. If it does it, when i run the Designer Application (`Application.Web.MVC`), it drops it again, and so on.

I don't know why is it doing this. I am not changing the models.

Comment: Do you have different solutions for these? If yes, what happens if there is only single solution containing both Web and API projects. Further, is database dropped every time you run any of project (or only when you switches the project between web & mvc)

Comment: Please ignore this question, i am stupid, i was actually pointing to a different database. It is all working. The good part is that this made me read about EF Code Migrations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ignore the question, it is all working. I was pointing to a different database.

Also, this was a good reason to learn about EF Migrations